# is there a graceful way to convert a String to Stream<Character>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<Character, Integer> getMap(String target) { 
return target.chars().boxed()
                      .map(c -> Character.valueOf((char) c.intValue()))
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                             c -> c, 
                             Collectors.reducing(0, c -> 1, Integer::sum)
                      ));
    }
```

this line `target.chars().boxed().map(c -> Character.valueOf((char) c.intValue()))` is really ugly, is there any better way to this?

Comment: I don’t think it’s *too* bad, but you are right, there is no point in boxing into `Integer` objects and unboxing them again.

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate `map()` operation when `groupingBy()` already expects a mapping function.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you've missed this:

```
Stream<Character> charStream = target.chars().mapToObj(i->(char)i);
```

`chars()` return the `IntStream` and the only thing you need to do is map each one to the character type by casting.

Answer (score 2):

@STaefi's answer is definitely the way to go if you want a `Stream<Character>`.

However, another way to make your code shorter and easier to follow is to represent the characters as strings and then you can do:

```
Map<String, Integer> getMap(String target) {
       return Arrays.stream(target.split(""))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                    Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)));
}
```

Comment: The potential advantage being…?

Comment: _to make your code shorter and easier to follow_ as stated in the answer. _readability_ is just as important in programming.

Comment: `Collectors.reducing(...)` could be replaced by `Collectors.counting()` if a `Map<String, Long>` is an acceptable type to be returned. If not, you could also use `Collectors.summingInt(ch -> 1)`.

Comment: @AlexisC. true, makes the code even more _readable_ now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a third-party library, you can write the following with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
Stream<Character> stream =
    CharAdapter.adapt("aaabbc").collect(Character::valueOf).stream();
```

This will convert the `char` values to `Character` objects and then give you a `Stream<Character>`.

If you want to count the Characters in a `String`, a [`Bag`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html) is a better choice than a `Map`. In Eclipse Collections, [`HashBag`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/bag/mutable/HashBag.html) is implemented using an [`ObjectIntHashMap`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/map/mutable/primitive/ObjectIntHashMap.html).  The following shows how you can count the `char` values or `Character` objects in a String.

```
CharBag charBag =
        CharAdapter.adapt("aaabbc").toBag();

Bag<Character> characterBag =
        CharAdapter.adapt("aaabbc").collect(Character::valueOf).toBag();

Assert.assertEquals(3, charBag.occurrencesOf('a'));
Assert.assertEquals(3, characterBag.occurrencesOf('a'));
```

The [`CharBag`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/primitive/CharBag.html) will not require any boxing of `Character` objects or `Integer` values for counts.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.